# Should I pay for Google Apps if I use my company domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

I registered for Google Apps a long time ago, when it was free for your small company.

Recently I learned about Google Apps for Work, I feel this is a rebranding of Google Apps, correct me if I'm wrong.

Can I use Google Apps for free with the advent of Google Apps for Work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can continue to use your Google Apps (once also called standard) if you still have access to it. Standard is no longer available for new accounts.

Google Apps for Work has more features so it is the next version rather than a rebrand.

They release new features all the time.  [See Here](https://apps.google.com/whatsnew/):
Other features:

- Much more storage space, 30GB today
- Device management (mobile and Chromebooks included)
- Security and Admin control tools
- Real 24/7 phone and email support

We still use this version but have no support other than reading support forums and no control over mobile devices.

Comment: What are these added features in Work?

Comment: They release new features all the time.  See Here: https://apps.google.com/whatsnew/